# af:inputFile component error in jsff page Oracle ADF

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf

I need help. I use Oracle JDeveloper 11g and I have a jsff page that I will input file on the server (is not a server is on my own local machine) and when I entered in to the page I have the following error:

```
<FormRenderer> <encodeAll> Multiple forms detected on viewId: /com/tech/law/pages/index.jspx.  Rich client currently has some limitations in dealing with multiple forms.
<AdfcExceptionHandler> <handleException> ADFc: No exception handler was found for an application exception.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.FormRenderer.encodeAll(FormRenderer.java:233)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1432)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:422)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:2788)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:438)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.DocumentRenderer.encodeAll(DocumentRenderer.java:1341)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1432)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.doRenderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:266)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:197)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:189)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:193)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._renderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:979)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:408)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:237)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:205)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:128)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:271)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:177)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

But I don't know how to fix it so please help. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Search your JSF code to see if you have the "form" element define more than once. Consider using subforms instead.